# Xfce workspace wrapping at horizontal edges only

Tags: xfce, workspaces

I want to wrap only at horizontal edges, not the vertical edges.
I have vertical panels and I don't want to change workspaces when my mouse pointer reaches it.

Comment: That comes across as a list of demands. Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: @roaima Obviously, “how do I configure XFCE to wrap workspaces at horizontal edges but not at vertical edges”.

Comment: I want to know how to configure it.